# Distributing processed SRTM data legally?

Tags: srtm, legal

I'm working on different maps, based on SRTM data.

The goal is to lay out the maps at a park entrance against a little money for the printing and my personal costs. The SRTM 4 data from CGIAR I origanally used prohibits the commercial use, so I'm not sure, if I'm allowed to do so.

Is there any SRTM data, free to use for that kind of purpose?

Comment: did you get a license agreement when you obtained your SRTM 4 data? Generally speaking if the data is available to download without signing a license agreement then the derived products are free to share, selling derived products could be a little sticky. Laws differ by country so any definitive advice would have to be based on your country.

Comment: I just saw, that the rights of the SRTM 4 data belong to CGIAR and are for non commercial use only. I wanted to lay out the maps at a park entrance against a little money for the printing and my personal costs. Is there any SRTM data, free to use for that purpose?

Comment: Read the license agreement carefully, you may need to acknowledge the use of the data and (depending on the laws in your country) may need to pay CGIAR for the use of their product.. though, if you are only seeking reimbursement for your time and materials it *should* be a different case. I could mention that it's unlikely that CGIAR has agents scouting for unlicensed use of their product...

Comment: It says Users are  prohibited from  any commercial,  non-free resale,  or redistribution without explicit written permission from CIAT. Users should acknowledge CIAT  as the source used  in the creation  of any reports,  publications, new data  sets, derived products, or services resulting from the use of this data set. CIAT also request  reprints of  any publications  and notification  of any  redistributing efforts. For commercial  access to  the data,  send requests  to Andy Jarvis. To be on the safe side contact Andy Jarvis and ask.

Comment: I think it will be the best. All this copyright stuff is very confusing. I also found some SRTM data under ODbL license, but it says I'm only allowed to use it, if i shared the result for free.

Comment: It can be very confusing, especially if like this case the data can be obtained for free. I get the feeling from their wording that they want to protect themselves from corporations making profit on their product not so much on a couple of maps for public display, especially as the maps aren't mass produced and resold. When you find out can you answer your own question with their response as I'm sure it will be of great interest to quite a few people.

Comment: In the meantime I recommend editing your brief question to include more of the details that you only mentioned in comments. That should help prevent any further downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Searching for `SRTM License` on Google brought me here. Not finding a satisfactory answer I decided to do my own research.

The Shuttle Radar Topography Mission (SRTM) is in the public domain, at least when downloaded from USGS; however, they ask that the following acknowledgment statement of the originating agency be included in products and data derived from map services when citing, copying, or reprinting:

"Map services and data available from U.S. Geological Survey, National Geospatial Program." (Source: [What are the Terms of Use/Licensing for map services and data from The National Map?](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-are-terms-uselicensing-map-services-and-data-national-map))

There is further evidence that SRTM data is in the Public Domain on [this page](https://www.usgs.gov/centers/eros/science/usgs-eros-archive-digital-elevation-shuttle-radar-topography-mission-srtm-non) where the image on the right is cited as "Sources/Usage: Public Domain.
Shuttle Radar Topography Mission (SRTM) Non-Void Filled North of Juneau, Alaska(Public domain)"

Information on how to download the SRTM data can be found here: [Where can I get global elevation data?](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/where-can-i-get-global-elevation-data)